# Architecture for Authentication/Authorization of Mobile and Web Users

Tags: web-services, authentication, architecture, mobile, authorization

This seems to be a reoccurring problem for me as I seem to gravitate around mobile applications the last few years. I want to authenticate and authorize mobile users in addition to web users. I need to make this seamless enough so that users can ease into having a web account without causing interruption to their data. I want the solution to be architectural in topic, not specific to any language/framework.

**Requirements/Assumptions**

1. Mobile users must be able to use the native application without a login, including for contributing content (marking favorites, uploading photos, etc).
2. Mobile user should be securely and uniquely authenticating to the web service even without specifying account credentials.
3. Mobile user may have multiple devices, which will be unaware of each other.
4. Mobile user should be able to Register/Login, which should roll in any content into the account's ownership. This "synchronization" should occur with each account that is subsequently logged in.
5. It should not matter whether an account was created on mobile or web.

**Architectures Considered**

1. **NO SHIRT, NO SHOES, NO LOGIN = NO CONTRIBUTION.** Require login to contribute content of any kind. This prevents the need to "synchronize" device accounts with a master account. Simply require a single username/password + tokens in order for devices to login. Server objects: User, Role
2. **Multi-device self-authentication.** Server negotiates with device and hands it credentials which the device stores. Each device self-authenticates and is associated with an anonymous account until Register/Login occurs. If Register occurs, anonymous account is converted into known account. If Login occurs, content from anonymous account is moved over to known account and then thrown away. Devices that lose the self-authentication details will get new authentication details, and the previous anonymous account is abandoned (and then hopefully later thrown away) and not restorable since it was never converted into a known account. Server objects: User, Role, Device

**What do you think is a good solution? One of these, or something else?**

Answer (score 2):

I would like to propose an idea similar to 2.

Generate an UUID per mobile device. It will serve to identify the device on later occurences when the user generates content and the content is sent to the server.

If, at any time later, the user wants to create an web account, he may register either on the web or on the device. If the user already owns a web account, he may opt to provide the existing credentials on his mobile device once (or devices) and the device is linked to his web account on the server-side.

On the server side, I would allow two different types of entities serving as identities: Web Users which are authenticated by credentials (OpenID comes to my mind as an addition) and devices which are authenticated by their GUID without user interference. Naturally, a web user entity may own several device entities. A device entity is linked to an account when the user opts to link his device to an existing account. Content is generally associated with an identity.

The linkage between user and device is kept and could also be used to display the origination of content.

You would not need to create/drop/convert accounts with generated credentials for mobile users. You would also not need to store the credentials on the mobile device.

There are still some security considerations left open, depending on the criticality of the context of your application. Without any security measures, an attacker would find it easy to abuse the UUID.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is being looked at from the wrong direction.  Define an identity on the server as being defined by an arbitrary value.  Probably just a DB sequence.  Associate any demographic information (name, email...) and usage history with this identity.

Separately, define an authentication entity on the server.  This could be a user/password.  It could be a device GUID/UUID.  It could be a federated ID like OpenID.  A given identity can have (and often will in your use-case) multiple associated authentication-entities.  Very possibly multiple authentication-identities of the same type.  (e.g. GUID for my smartphone, GUID for my iPad...)

Your front-ends (whether web or app-based), use a defined API to authenticate a user; using whichever of the mechanisms that front-end supports.

In some cases (particularly the native app), the presentation of an unknown ID triggers the creation of a new identity.  However, as someone pointed out, in this situation you should ask the user if they want to connect to an existing identity.  They need to provide authentication as that identity (once) in order to establish that connection.

One other point, whatever the server uses to uniquely specify an identity should be a value that is *never* provided to a client.  Clients only know about the authentication mechanism and its data.  That is, the GUID/UUID, username/password,...

In addition to the techniques listed above, something like OAuth is more secure than a locally-generated GUID.  Those are one of a: easily-determined or b: easily-lost.  If the value is highly predictable (say telephone #) it is easily spoofed.  If it is generated at runtime and includes a hard-to-predict value like the hash of the current time when it is first generated, then it must be stored on the device and can be easily lost if the device is wiped.  Good GUIDs can be generated, but they are often very type-of-device specific.  Things like device serial numbers retrieved from ROM, IMEIs,...  This is readily doable.  But, is a lot more specific-device dependent than I'd likely be comfortable with.

The biggest real hurdle I see in this whole approach is that it will be awkward to allow an existing device-only (no username/password) user to sit down at a PC browser and connect to his existing account.

Comment: I really like your line of thinking. I'm not sure it really illustrates common techniques to approach this particular problem, but I'm very appreciative of your response. (Note that I read this response back in 2010, but I felt compelled to let you know now that it was appreciated and useful)

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 is good enough as base decision. Users hate registration ;) So ability to use service without registration is good idea.

You can use GUID/UUID to identify devise. And use it as anonymous login before user login.

But what to do if 2 (or more) people use 1 device? Or device will be losed, stolen?
I think no one of the points cover these cases.

I have no idea what kind of web service you architect so can't advise more.

Answer (score -3):

One solution is with a biometric. If the mobile device has biometric sensor, such as a finger print reader, user will enroll biometric with the device (only- due to privacy issues) at the time of purchase. The applications can be written such that every secure transaction requires the user to authenticate the biometric.

This does not seem to be too far off. Motorola Atrix has a fingerprint sensor...

Comment: This response does not really address the post as was presented. Certainly biometrics can help to identify the user, but connecting that device and user authentication to a backend will still require some design considerations. I have still not come across a perfect solution.